# How to generate @OneToOne and @ManyToMany JPA relations in Telosys using Dsl Model

Tags: java, jpa, telosys

Im trying to generate classes using my own springboot template and Dsl models. In my ".entity" files I have:

```
Car {​​​​​
id : int {​​​​​ @Id, @AutoIncremented }​​​​​;
users : Employee [];
}​​​​​
    
Employee {​​​​​
id : long {​​​​​ @Id }​​​​​ ;
name : string ;
cars : Car[] ;
}​​​​​
```

I was expecting a @ManyToMany relation in JPA but I didn't. The same thing with this:

```
Car {​​​​​
id : int {​​​​​ @Id, @AutoIncremented }​​​​​;
user : Employee;
}​​​​​
    
Employee {​​​​​
id : long {​​​​​ @Id }​​​​​ ;
name : string ;
car : Car;
}​​​​​
```

I expect a @OneToOne relation but I don't get it. It seems I can only get @ManyToOne and @OneToMany.
How can I get @ManyToMany and @OneToOne relations using DSL models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **Telosys 3.3.0** you can do that with
“**@OneToOne**” and “**@ManyToMany**” DSL model annotations.

Add annotation for the relevant link, for example :

```
MyEntity {
  ...
  employee : Employee  { @OneToOne   @FetchTypeLazy  } ; 
  projects : Project[] { @ManyToMany @LinkByJoinEntity(EmpProj) } ;
}
```

See the doc :

- https://doc.telosys.org/dsl-model/attribute-annotations#manytomany
- https://doc.telosys.org/dsl-model/attribute-annotations#onetoone

Comment: If I want to express the same relationships in a c# asp.net core project and entity framework model, are these annotation usable? is lang C# env variable of use? How to generated C# equivalent of JPA classes